# ubuntu - disable logging to syslog from a specific process/from the rsyslog process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, syslog, rsyslog

I have an **ubuntu** machine, and a server app running on it.

I also have rsyslog running which collects logs from the server app and write it to my own logs.

The issue I am having is that, it seems that the messages that are sent to **rsyslog** from the server app, are also written in **var/logs/syslog**.

How can I disable this? I don't want any of the server-app related messages that are sent to **rsyslog** to appear in **var/logs/syslog**.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `& stop;` at the next line following the command that writes to your logfile.